# compute the correlation between X and Y?

Tags: probability

I am staying for a final and reviewing old questions again that I got wrong on my homework. The question I am having trouble with is this.

"Suppose the random variables $X$ and $Y$ are jointly uniformly distributed in the region bounded by the $x-$axis and the curve $y=25-x^2$. Compute the correlation between X and Y."

I know the correlation correlation formula is 
$$\rho = \frac{\sigma_{X,Y}}{\sigma_X \, \sigma_Y}$$

I also know the covariance formula:

$$\sigma_{X,Y}=    Cov[X,Y] = E[X Y]-E[X]E[Y]$$

Also I have already graphed the function $y=25-x^2$ for positive $y$. Which is just a negative parabola intersecting the $x-$axis at $x=-25$ and $x=25$ and the $y-$axis at $y=25$.

However I don't know how to use this information to find the correlation between $X$ and $Y$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint 1:

The intuitive-informal meaning of the correlation is: when $X,Y$ are positively correlated ($\rho >0$), to know that $X$ is "large" (greater than its mean $E[X]$) leads as to bet that $Y$ will also be (probably) "large" (greater than its mean $E[Y]$). And viceversa. To be negatively correlated means the reverse.

In other words, a large positive correlation means that the variables tend (very loosely speaking) to cluster along a line (regression line) with positive slope. Negative correlation means that the regression line has negative slope.

[image]

(image from [here](http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/arcgisdesktop/com/gp_toolref/spatial_statistics_toolbox/regression_analysis_basics.htm)).

If you understand this interpretation, then it should be obvious that the correlation here is zero.

Hint 2:

Using the definition of correlation, show that if the joint density is **uniform over a symmetric region** (with respect to the axis $X$ or the axis $Y$ - or, more generally, with respect to any vertical or horizontal line) then the variables are uncorrelated.

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to use the definitions.

The distribution has density $f(x,y) = \frac{1}{\int_{-5}^5 \int_0^{25-x^2} dy dx}$ on the prescribed region, and zero otherwise.

$E[X] = \int_{-5}^5 \int_0^{25-x^2} x f(x,y) dy dx$

$E[Y] = \int_{-5}^5 \int_0^{25-x^2} y f(x,y) dy dx$

$E[XY] = \int_{-5}^5 \int_0^{25-x^2} xy f(x,y) dy dx$

Note that $f(x,y)$ is just a number, $\frac{1}{\int_{-5}^5 \int_0^{25-x^2} dy dx}$ in these integrals.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint #1**: Since the joint PDF is uniform over the region $\{y \leq 25-x^2, -5\leq x \leq 5\}$, it has the form

$$
f_{X,Y}(x,y)=
\left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
C & 0\leq y\leq 25 - x^2, -5\leq x \leq 5\\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{array}
\right .
$$

where $C$ is a constant. What should be the value of $C$? Find  it out integrating over both variables and applying the normalization axiom:

\begin{align}
1 &= \int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{-\infty}^\infty f_{X,Y}(x,y)dydx\\
&=\int_{-5}^5\int_{0}^{25-x^2} Cdydx
\end{align}

**Hint #2**: The correlation between $X$ and $Y$ is defined as

\begin{align}
E[XY] &= \int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{-\infty}^\infty xyf_{X,Y}(x,y)dydx\\
&= \int_{-5}^5\int_{0}^{25-x^2} Cxydydx
\end{align}